# AVD - No prgramming changes applied

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, egit, eclipse-3.6

I recently updated my version of eclipse from 3.6 to 3.7 
(Using Mac OS X 10.6.8 & Eclipse 3.7).  I did this to install EGit.  Since, then I have noticed that none of the changes to my App are being reflected in my AVD's.

When setting up EGit I realized that it had moved my working location to another location on my system.  I figured this might be the issue, so I removed my EGit repository and restored my App from a backup.  The problem continue leading me to believe the problem likely lies (I could be wrong) with the upgrade to Eclipse 3.7.

I have tried many other things, but none seem to work. So far I have..

Uninstalled my App from the AVD, and then re-ran application.  This made no difference.
I have tried creating a new fresh AVD.  Same deal here, same un-change version of app is applied.
I tried stop and restarting the adb.
I have tried to 'Clean up' the Project.

All attempts so far have failed.

Has anyone else out there seen this problem or have any suggestions?
I think the next thing I might try is updating my Android plug-ins.  If this fails I Afraid my next option is to uninstall Eclipse completely and start from scratch.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

My guess of updating the Android SDK was correct.
In Elipse I went to Window -> Android SDK Manager.
I installed the available updates:
Android SDK Tools 22.0.1,
Android SDK Platform-Tools 17,
Android SDK Build Tools 17.  After the install restarted Eclipse and then boom!  My AVD was back and showing my newest changes.  Hope this helps some one.